# How to implement memoization in Scala without mutability?

Tags: scala, thread-safety, immutability, memoization, category-theory

I was recently reading Category Theory for Programmers and in one of the challenges, Bartosz proposed to write a function called *memoize* which takes a function as an argument and returns the same one with the difference that, the first time this new function is called, it stores the result of the argument and then returns this result each time it is called again.

```scala
def memoize[A, B](f: A => B): A => B = ???
```

The problem is, I can't think of any way to implement this function without resorting to mutability. Moreover, the implementations I have seen uses mutable data structures to accomplish the task.

My question is, is there a purely functional way of accomplishing this? Maybe without mutability or by using some functional trick?

Thanks for reading my question and for any future help. Have a nice day!

Comment: There is no way to accomplish that without mutability AFAIK - And that doesn't make it less functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a purely functional way of accomplishing this?

No. Not in the narrowest sense of pure functions and using the given signature.

TLDR: Use mutable collections, it's okay!

### Impurity of `g`

```scala
val g = memoize(f)
// state 1
g(a)
// state 2
```

What would you expect to happen for the call `g(a)`?

If `g(a)` memoizes the result, an (internal) state has to change, so the state is different after the call `g(a)` than before.
As this could be observed from the outside, the call to `g` has side effects, which makes your program impure.

From the Book you referenced, `2.5 Pure and Dirty Functions`:

> [...] functions that
>
> - always produce the same result given the same input and
> - **have no side effects**
>
> are called *pure functions*.

### Is this really a side effect?

Normally, at least in Scala, *internal* state changes are **not** considered side effects.

See the definition in the [Scala Book](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/pure-functions.html)

> A pure function is a function that depends only on its declared inputs and its internal algorithm to produce its output. It does not read any other values from “the outside world” — **the world outside of the function’s scope** — and it does not modify any values in the outside world.

The following examples of lazy computations both change their internal states, but are normally still considered purely functional as they always yield the same result and have no side effects apart from internal state:

```scala
lazy val x = 1
// state 1: x is not computed
x
// state 2: x is 1
```

```scala
val ll = LazyList.continually(0)
// state 1: ll = LazyList(<not computed>)
ll(0)
// state 2: ll = LazyList(0, <not computed>)
```

In your case, the equivalent would be something using a private, mutable Map (as the implementations you may have found) like:

```scala
def memoize[A, B](f: A => B): A => B = {
  val cache = mutable.Map.empty[A, B]
  (a: A) => cache.getOrElseUpdate(a, f(a))
}
```

Note that the cache is not public.
So, for a *pure* function `f` and without looking at memory consumption, timings, reflection or other evil stuff, you won't be able to tell from the outside whether `f` was called twice or `g` cached the result of `f`.

In this sense, side effects are only things like printing output, writing to public variables, files etc.

Thus, this implementation is considered *pure* (at least in Scala).

### Avoiding mutable collections

If you *really* want to avoid `var` and mutable collections, you need to change the signature of your `memoize` method.
This is, because if `g` cannot change internal state, it won't be able to memoize anything new after it was initialized.

An (inefficient but simple) example would be

```scala
def memoizeOneValue[A, B](f: A => B)(a: A): (B, A => B) = {
  val b = f(a)
  val g = (v: A) => if (v == a) b else f(v)
  (b, g)
}

val (b1, g) = memoizeOneValue(f, a1)
val (b2, h) = memoizeOneValue(g, a2)
// ...
```

The result of `f(a1)` would be cached in `g`, but nothing else. Then, you could chain this and always get a new function.

If you are interested in a faster version of that, see @esse's answer, which does the same, but more efficient (using an immutable map, so `O(log(n))` instead of the linked list of functions above, `O(n)`).

Comment: I really like when someone takes the effort and time to write well formatted, nice and dedicated answers like this, so thank you so so much! Also, I was really hoping for something like that could be done :/ BTW, the lazy evaluation give me an idea of how this could be accomplish, so thanks also for that!

Answer (score 1):

Let's [try](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/66weX4WITpiJ70ssK8RT7w)(**Note**: I have change the return type of memoize to store the cached data):

```
import scala.language.existentials

type M[A, B] = A => T forSome { type T <: (B, A => T) }

def memoize[A, B](f: A => B): M[A, B] = {
  import scala.collection.immutable
  
  def withCache(cache: immutable.Map[A, B]): M[A, B] = a => cache.get(a) match {
    case Some(b) => (b, withCache(cache))
    case None    =>
      val b = f(a)
      (b, withCache(cache + (a -> b)))
  }
  withCache(immutable.Map.empty)
}


def f(i: Int): Int = { print(s"Invoke f($i)"); i }


val (i0, m0) = memoize(f)(1)    // f only invoked at first time
val (i1, m1) = m0(1)
val (i2, m2) = m1(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is pure functional ways to implement polymorphic function memoization. The topic is surprisingly deep and even summons the [Yoneda Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma), which is likely what Bartosz had in mind with this exercise.

The blog post [Memoization in Haskell](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-14-memoization-in-hasekll.html) gives a nice introduction by simplifying the problem a bit: instead of looking at arbitrary functions it restricts the problem to functions from the integers.

> The following memoize function takes a function of type Int -> a and
> returns a memoized version of the same function. The trick is to turn
> a function into a value because, in Haskell, functions are not
> memoized but values are. memoize converts a function f :: Int -> a
> into an infinite list [a] whose nth element contains the value of f n.
> Thus each element of the list is evaluated when it is first accessed
> and cached automatically by the Haskell runtime thanks to lazy
> evaluation.

```
memoize :: (Int -> a) -> (Int -> a)
memoize f = (map f [0 ..] !!)
```

Apparently the approach can be generalised to function of arbitrary domains. The trick is to come up with a way to use the type of the domain as an index into a lazy data structure used for "storing" previous values. And this is [where the Yoneda Lemma comes in](http://conal.net/blog/posts/memoizing-polymorphic-functions-via-unmemoization) and my own understanding of the topic becomes flimsy.

Comment: I was actually thinking about this, I even have another question in Stack Overflow asking how to store all outputs of a function inside a Lazy List. But in Scala that appears to be really hard to implement :/ Anyway, thanks for your answer! I was hoping of something like this to exist.

Comment: Bartosz talks a bit about function memoization in the chapter about representable functors: https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/07/29/representable-functors/